# Trouble understanding why fields are unnaffected by translations

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, coordinate-systems, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

The following sentence appears in my classical field theory notes

> Fields are Lorentz tensors and spinors, and as such unaffected by translations: $ \dfrac{\delta \phi}{\delta a^{\alpha}}=0.$

Where $a^{\alpha}$ are the parameters of the Poincaré group.

From my understanding $\delta \phi = \phi (x^{\mu} + a^{\mu}) - \phi (x^{\mu})$ and should be different from zero if the field isn't uniform in spacetime.

Could someone clarify this?

Edit: the notes can be read here -
http://www.ift.unesp.br/users/jpereira/ClassiFields.pdf - and the above statement is in page 91.

Comment: You’re both right. They simply mean that nothing happens besides just translating the field value.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you could provide a link (or at least a screenshot), because without context it is hard to say much.

However, the statement as written is wrong, and you are absolutely right to correct it.

I suspect that the sentence should be understood as “fields are invariant under *passive* translations”, meaning that the coordinate system is deagged, not the field itself. In other words, accompanying the translation there’s a change in origin, which compensates the effect of translation.

Note that fields of nonzero spin aren’t invariant under passive rotations, so the statement above actually contains nontrivial information.

Comment: Here in page 91 : http://www.ift.unesp.br/users/jpereira/ClassiFields.pdf

Comment: @Slayer147 you should edit that link (together with a full reference) into the question.